# EntityFramework no actualiza algunos campos

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo un problema con EntityFramework-6, estoy intentando crear una entidad "desconectada" para simplemente guardar los cambios de los campos que yo deseo.

Mi contexto (DataContext.cs) tiene un miembro llamado Demos, y ese tipo de entidad (Demo.cs) deriva de una clase llamada ModelBase.

En mi base de datos, se crea como tal mi tabla de "Demo" como lo tengo en el DataContent.

Al guardar los cambios, EF, únicamente me guarda los cambios de la clase Demo.cs y no los que hereda de ModelBase.cs.

Este es el código que falla:

```csharp
using (var contexto = new DataContext())
{
    // Creo la entidad.
    var demo = new Demo { Id = 1 };

    // Lo agrego al control de cambios.
    context.Demos.Attach(demo);

    // Este cambio si lo actualiza.
    obj.Nombre = "Carlos";

    // Este cambio NO LO ACTUALIZA.
    obj.Modified = DateTime.Now;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Este otro ejemplo si funciona:

```csharp
using (var contexto = new DataContext())
{
    // Creo la entidad.
    var demo = new Demo { Id = 1 };

    // Lo agrego al control de cambios.
    context.Demos.Attach(demo);

    // Este cambio si lo actualiza.
    demo.Nombre = "Carlos";

    // Este cambio si lo actualiza si lo especifico explicitamente.
    demo.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    context.Entry(demo).Property(x => x.Modified).IsModified = true;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

*DataContext*

```csharp
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Models.Demo> Demos { get; set; }
}
```

*Demo.cs*

```csharp
public class Demo : ModelBase
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public string Apellidos { get; set; }
}
```

*ModelBase.cs*

```csharp
public class ModelBase : Core.DataAccessLayer.IModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Crea una nueva instancia de <see cref="ModelBase"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public ModelBase()
    {
        this.Created = DateTime.Now;
        this.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene o establece el identificador de un registro.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene o establece la fecha de creación.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene o establece la fecha de modificación.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**

Marqué los campos de ModelBase como "virtual", y ahora si lo actualiza, sin embargo no es constantes.

En algunos casos ejecuta esta consulta:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Demoes]
SET [Nombres] = @0, [Modified] = @1
WHERE ([Id] = @2)
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 datetime2(7),@2 int',@0=N'25/05/2016 9:02:18',@1='2016-05-25 09:02:18.7027657',@2=1
```

Y en otras ocasiones esto:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Demoes]
SET [Nombres] = @0
WHERE ([Id] = @1)
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int',@0=N'25/05/2016 9:02:14',@1=1
```

Comment: ¿Y aplicastes migraciones?

Comment: Si, en la base de datos existe ya la tabla con el registro de esta prueba.

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto como funciona la consulta ya que el `UPDATE` solo aplica a los campos que hayan sido marcados como `Dirty` o sea aquellas propiedades que cambiaron, si no lo hacen no se reflejarán en el UPDATE.

Si recomendaría es a una entidad desconectada del contexto cuando la incluyes debes marcarle el estado.

```
using (var contexto = new DataContext())
{
    var demo = new Demo { Id = 1 };

    context.Entry(demo).State = EntityState.Modified; 

    obj.Nombre = "Carlos";
    obj.Modified = DateTime.Now;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

[Add/Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Por que no intentas hacer lo que propone Leandro y despues de eso pues haces migracion de la base de datos.

usando este comando en la consola de administrador de paquetes.

Aqui te dejo un link que te puede servir.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/data/jj554735.aspx

En caso de de que te mande errores en la migracion, debido a que suele fallar.
podrias crear otra cadena de conexion y pues que te cree una base de datos nueva ya sea en SQL o la local. y pues solo cargas los datos nuevamente.